2005 toyota camry p0420 do I need to replace secondary catalytic converter?
I have a 2005 Toyota Camry, 2.4l engine. The P0420 code went on and after using catalclean  and cleaning overnight with dish soap (didn't work), I've elected to replace the exhaust manifold catalytic converter (cat 1).
Questions:

Do I need to also replace the secondary catalytic cleaner (cat 2)? As the secondary O2 sensor is downstream of the secondary catalytic converter, would replacing the exhaust manifold work to eliminate the code?
Do I need to purchase the California CARB versions? Original car was purchased in CA, but I live in GA now.


Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You are stating you tried to clean the cat with dish soap (mixed with water, I take it)?

Check with your state's dmv about emissions regulations and replacement parts. Several states do not have emissions regulations. Other states allows non OEM parts for replacement. This can drastically reduce costs for replacing catalytic converters with lower cost aftermarket parts. The catalytic converter with the downstream O2 sensor (not the one on the exhaust manifold upstream of the catcon) may be the one to replace.

@paulster2 Yep, didn't work clearly. @f dryer, From what I can tell, OEM and aftermarket parts are similar in price (difference within a hundred dollars). I've updated the post with a photo. May you confirm what you meant?
